# Can't parse nested string template

Tags: python, python-2.7

I used pymongo to parse mongo query, I had a function that accepts multiple variables that parse into mongo query. I got an error `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` on template's **safe_substitute** method.

```
from string import Template
from bson.objectid import ObjectId

template = Template({"${key}":{"${condition}": ObjectId("${value}") }})
mongo_filter = template.safe_substitute(key=key, condition='${}'.format(condition), value=value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [Template documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/node109.html), the method `safe_substitute` only accepts **string or bytes-like object**. In your case, you are passing `ObjectId` which mismatch the acceptable types.

Therefore, you **can't use** python Template method with your `ObjectId`.

However, you can parse your variables into nested object in single variable without using any library.

**Solution**

```
nestedObject = {
  key: {
    condition: ObjectId(value)
  }
}
```

where `key`, `condition`, `value` are variables to parse into nested object.